# PySpark DataFrame: extract numbers from string

Tags: python, regex, pyspark

I have spark dataframe with string column

| id | str_data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {{{1111, 2023-02-07}, null, 88.92.1, text, 2023},[{{'1111', date='2023-02-07'}, null, 41.5, text_1, 2023}, {{'1111', date='2023-02-08'}, null, 15.59, text_2, 2023}]} |
| 2 | {{{2222, 2023-02-07}, null, 25.87, text_3, 2023},[{{'2222, date='2023-02-07'}, null, 33.5.1, text_4, 2023}, {{'2222', date='2023-02-08'}, null, 15.59, text_5, 2023}, {{'2222', date='2023-02-08'}, null, 01.1.5, text_6, 2023}]} |
| ... | ... |

Each row can contain different amount of data (from 2 to 15) and length of "text" can vary. I need to collect all numbers (88.92.1, 41.5 and 15.59 from first row in my example OR at least all numbers in [] - 41.5 and 15.59 from first row in my example) per id.

Here is one of my attempts:

```
sdf.withColumn('str_data', split('str_data', r'[a-zA-Z]'))
sdf.withColumn('str_data', array_remove('str_data', ''))
```

Which gives me almost no changes

| id | str_data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{{{1111, 2023-02-07}, , , 88.92.1, text, 2023},[{{'1111', date='2023-02-07'}, , , 41.5, text_1, 2023}, {{'1111', date='2023-02-08'}, , , 15.59, text_2, 2023}]} |

Output that i want:

| id | str_data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [88.92.1, 41.5, 15.59] |

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/vD40hE/1  
With this regex, you have the group which contains your expected numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but some numbers have several dots, so this regex returns 92.1 instead of 88.92.1 and 1.5 instead of 01.1.5

Comment: updated https://regex101.com/r/vD40hE/4

Answer (score 1):

If your `pyspark` version supports [`regexp_extract_all`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#regexp_extract_all) function then solution is:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn('str_data', F.regexp_extract_all('str_data', '\d+\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?', 0))
```

---

Otherwise it's achievable with `udf` function, slower (but working):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType
import re

pat = re.compile(r'\d+\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?')

def regexp_extract_all(col, pat):
    return re.findall(pat, col)

df = df.withColumn('str_data', F.udf(lambda col, pat=pat: regexp_extract_all(col, pat), 
                                     ArrayType(StringType()))('str_data'))

df.show(truncate=False)
```

---

```
+---+------------------------------+
|id |str_data                      |
+---+------------------------------+
|1  |[88.92.1, 41.5, 15.59]        |
|2  |[25.87, 33.5.1, 15.59, 01.1.5]|
+---+------------------------------+
```